# Google Colaboratory - Won't Start Error

Tags: colab

Has anyone else encountered this error?  I am teaching a business analytics class with python this semester and Colab has been absolutely fantastic, yet one student is getting the following error.

[image]

Any thoughts or advice would be very helpful!

Comment: Hmm, this looks like a bug. What version of Safari are you using? Is it possible to use Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: I reached out to the student and will follow up when I have more details on versions.  Right now it appears to be isolated to one student.